# Post Build event is executing before the msi is built in visual studio with wix sharp

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, wix, wixsharp

I have several projects which generates several references.
and in the installer project which ultimately generates a MSI file; using WIX sharp.

There are pre build events written to copy the reference from different folder to the packaging folder of the MSI. It is working fine the MSI is generating successfully.

Now I want to sign the MSI with a code signing certificate, the Issue is **post build event is executing before the MSI build** is started and since there is no MSI present the build is getting errors.

I am using Visual studio 2017.

The post build code I am executing

```
$(ProjectDir)signtool\signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /sm /sha1 [hash] $(ProjectDir)\test.msi
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't  sign your MSI in **Post-Build** event if you really use **WixSharp**, because MSI package creates by call **ManagedProject.BuildMsi()** method in runtime.

So i see only one workaround here, you need to call **Process.Start("signtool\signtool.exe ...")"** after **BuildMsi()** method execution

Comment: That's actually even better than postbuild event because you can detect windows kit sdk version easily